# Java/Cucumber/Spring : Fail to read in custom application.properties files

Tags: java, spring, cucumber

I have Java/Cucumber project using Spring to manage beans.
Using io.cucumber jars version 4.2.0, spring-context and spring-test version 5.0.9
Java version 1.8.0_152

I can inject property sources using

```
@Configuration
@PropertySource("application-dev.properties")
@PropertySource("application-test.properties")
@PropertySource("application-staging.properties")
public class MyConfig {

  private property1

  @Autowired
  private Environment env;

  @PostConstruct
  private void init() {
    if ((env.getProperty("dev")!=null)&&(env.getProperty("dev").equals("true"))) {
      // set dev config
      property1 = env.getProperty("dev-property1);
    }
    else if ((env.getProperty("test")!=null)&&(env.getProperty("test").equals("true"))) {
      // set test config
      property1 = env.getProperty("test-property1);
    }
    if ((env.getProperty("staging")!=null)&&(env.getProperty("staging").equals("true"))) {
      // set staging config
      property1 = env.getProperty("staging-property1);
    }
```

I run the application with the -Ddev="true" JVM argument

I want to avoid the if-nest (there are many properties in the properties files).
I tried using -Dspring.profiles.active=dev, and have Spring automagically pick up the correct application-dev.properties file.

```
@Configuration
// deleted the @PropertySource lines
public class MyConfig {

  @Value("{$spring.profiles.active}")
  private String activeProfile;

  @Value("{$property1}")
  private property1

}
```

But this does not work.  activeProfile is set to "dev" ok, but no application-dev.properties properties are loaded. I can't see an application-dev.properties in the env

What am I missing?

Comment: You are trying to get `dev-property1` in first snippet and `property1` in second one. Can you show your properties files? Are they in resources path?

Comment: That's correct. In the first snippet I am copying env.getProperty("dev-property1") etc to property1. In the second snippet I am trying to get Spring to set property1 from $property1 in the active profile in application-dev.properties. The application-dev.properties file in in src/main/resources directory and contains key value pairs, including property1=xxx. I'm not getting the contents of application-dev.properties fed through to the application.